# MYSQLI - Script keeps inserting empty data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble with my insert script. I can't seem to get my script to stop inserting empty data into mysql. I tried using !empty function. But yet it still submits it into the database. Here's my code:

```
<?php


  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' );


  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }



if (!empty($_POST)) {

  // Insert into posts
  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, postdata ) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['title'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['data'])}' )";
  $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

  // Print response from MySQL
  if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
  } else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
  }

  // Close our connection
  $mysqli->close();
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<br>
<br>
Title:
<br>
<input type="text" name="title">

<br>
<br>
Post:
<br>
<textarea name="data" id="data"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Does the post data contain the data you are trying to fetch? Also, instead of escaping values and putting them in the query (which could also be kinda unsafe, even though more safe than not escaping it), you could use prepared statements!

Comment: What does `$sql` output as?

Comment: Yes, the script works fine, but you can press submit with nothing entered and it'll just keep inserting blank data, what I am trying to go for is to make the query fail if the post data is empty

Comment: Check your fields, `$_POST['title']` and `$_POST['data']`, rather than just `$_POST`. You also can add initial client side check (don't rely on that though, have server side too).

Comment: Can you confirm that as you refresh the page, it inserts into the database?

Comment: The ***less*** the good people know, the ***more time*** it takes to provide you with a solution. Which in turn, you're asking us to take a blind shot at an invisible target.. That means "code" which includes the associated HTML form for this.

Comment: @TheCodesee yes wheen you refresh it continues to insert

Comment: and I am out of this one. Good luck gentlemen (and possibly ladies).

Comment: @Fred-ii- common sense would say if I can post data using my inputs then I guess there's nothing wrong with the html? Or did you forget I titled it MYSQLI? Not html.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will automatically insert into the database when the page loads.

As a workaround, you should add `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` which will only insert into the database when the form is submitted.

The code will also check if `$_POST['title']` is empty and displays an error if so.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if(empty($_POST['title'])) {
      echo 'Please fill in the field.';
   }else{
      $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, postdata ) VALUES ( '{$mysqli-real_escape_string($_POST['title'])}', '{$mysqli-real_escape_string($_POST['data'])}' )";
      $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
   }
}
```

As you failed to supply your `form`, I'm guessing that the name of the `submit` button is submit.

Comment: That won't stop empty data fields.

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you very much.

Comment: As I mentioned above the form still inserts when you press submit when the variables $_POST ['title'] and$_POST ['title'] are empty

Comment: @MichaelToole Check my updated answer. It checks if `$_POST['title']`  is empty. If so, it displays an error. If not, it inserts into the database.